# Project plane on a specific distance using Three.js

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d

I have a rectangle defined by 4 points. I want to move it to the left or right by specific distance. By moving I mean that result rectangle should be parallel to the original and if we put straights through corresponding points we will get rectangular cuboid.

On an image I am given coordinates of points A,B,C,D and distance H.
How can I calculate 4 new points using Three.js?
[image: Dedede]

I guess it has something to do with projection, but I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

Comment: Add H to all your 4 vertices. If you want to know how to do this in three.js specifically, then please share with us how your rectangle is defined in your code at the moment.

Comment: @Berthur Right now it's defined as 4 Vector3 objects.

Comment: And do you want to do the extrusion in the direction of some axis, or into any direction? If you want to extrude by 1 into the negative x axis, for instance, you can do `const a1 = new THREE.Vector3(a.x - 1, a.y, a.z);`.

Comment: If you want this to work in any direction in space, but parallel to the original rectangle, then you can calculate your extrude direction as the cross product of *AB* and *AD*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Answer (score 1):

Just an example. Aqua lines are base, yellow lines are shifted ones:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 5);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let dir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
let colors = [];
let ptsBase = [
  [-1, 1], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, -1]
].map(p => {
  colors.push(0, 1, 1);
  return new THREE.Vector3(p[0], p[1], 0);
});

let ptsShift = ptsBase.map(p => {
  colors.push(1, 1, 0);
  return p.clone().addScaledVector(dir, 2)
});
let ptsFinal = ptsBase.concat(ptsShift);

let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(ptsFinal);
g.setIndex([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7]);
g.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
let m = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({vertexColors: true});
let l = new THREE.LineSegments(g, m);
scene.add(l);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found to be working is getting normal vector, multiplying it by distance, and adding it to my point vectors.

I did it like this

```
let pointA = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
let pointB = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
let pointC = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0);
let pointD = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
const distance = 0.5;

let triangle = new THREE.Triangle(pointA, pointB, pointC);

let plane = new THREE.Plane();
triangle.getPlane(plane);

let normalVector = plane.normal.multiplyScalar(distance);

pointA1 = pointA.clone().add(normalVector);
pointB1 = pointB.clone().add(normalVector);
pointC1 = pointC.clone().add(normalVector);
pointD1 = pointD.clone().add(normalVector);
```